# Read Sqlite View Definition in R

Tags: r, sqlite

Is there a way to see the view definition in R when connecting to a Sqlite database?

I've tried using the function dbListTables but the view shows up as a table

Comment: You should put together a minimal reproducible example to show us what you did, and give more details about what you want to see instead.